# Transform my data or use the original data in my multiple regression analysis?

Tags: multiple-regression

I have three independent variables and one dependent variable (two separate questions which I want to analyse seperately against the tree independent variables). I want to look at the relationship between the three independent variables on the dependent variable.

I have made a mean score on each of the independent variables, and it is negatively skewed. 
IV 1 = s:-,475     IV 2 = s:-,797      IV 3 = s:-,535
For my dependent variable: DV 1 = s:-,874        DV 2 = s: -1,406

Can I do a multiple regression with these data's? I know it's probably difficult answering without seeing the data, but I have tried looking on the web and in books for answers, but not figured it out.

I have tried to transform them (as it says in the book when it is negatively skewed). Before I transformed them, I reversed the scores. The log10 helped a lot with the independent variables, but not on the dependent variable.

My second question is: Since I did not succeed transforming the dependent variable, I can not do a multiple regression with the transformed data's (I guess). Do you think my original data are decent enough to do the analysis with or do I have to do something else?

Looking forward hearing your answers.